# Convergent bounded net of positive operators converges to a positive operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Endow $A$ with the strict topology for which a net $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ converges to $a \in A$ if $$\|a_i b-ab\| + \|ba_i-ba\| \to 0$$
for all $b \in A$. Is it true that if $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a bounded net of positive elements that converges strictly to $a \in A$, then $a$ is also positive?

Remarks: (1) If $A$ is unital, the strict topology coincides with the norm-topology and the result is well-known then.

(2) If $A= B_0(H)$, then the strict topology on bounded subsets of $A$ is the strong$^*$- topology and then the statement is obviously true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $a$ is positive, too.

*Proof.*
For every $b \in A$ we have $b^* a_i b \to b^* a b$, so $b^*a b$ is positive.
Now, let $(e_j)$ be an approximate identity in $A$. Then it follows that $(e_j a e_j)$ is a net of positive elements that converges in norm to $a$; hence, $a$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you perhaps know if this is still true if $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a net in $M(A)$ and if $a \in M(A)$?

Comment: I can add a bounty if you answer this as well.

Comment: Yes, since $x\in M(A)$ is positive if and only if $a^\ast xa$ is positive for every $a\in A$ (this is easy to see if you represent $A\subseteq B(H)$ non-degenerately and consider $M(A) \subseteq B(H)$ as the idealiser of $A$). The OP should consider posting some of their questions to MathStackExchange instead of Mathoverflow, remember that Mathoverflow is for research questions.